# Add sublists to arraylist via for loop

Tags: java, arraylist, sublist

How do I add the sublists I've made with a for loop to an ArrayList? Considering the number of sublists could potentially be hundreds, or even thousands. I know the code below is a no go, since the addAll need to have a list as a parameter, but it's the kinda thing I'm after.

```
List<Integer> list1 = arrayList.subList(0, 3);
List<Integer> list2 = arrayList.subList(3, 6);
List<Integer> list3 = arrayList.subList(6, 9);
ArrayList<Integer> newArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    String listNum = "list" + i;
    newArray.addAll(listNum);
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: An array with all the lists as one.

Comment: Why are u adding a string to newArray, which is ArrayList<Integer>? It seems you are missing some basic java knowlegde. listNum is a String, you can't make it point to an ArrayList by matching the names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot "address" a local variable by index - you need an array for that:

```
List<Integer>[] list = new List<Integer>[] {
    arrayList.subList(0, 3)
,   arrayList.subList(3, 6)
,   arrayList.subList(6, 9)
};
ArrayList<Integer> newArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    newArray.addAll(list.get(i));
}
```

In your specific example you can construct sublist on the fly, without storing them in an array:

```
ArrayList<Integer> newArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    newArray.addAll(arrayList.subList(3*i, 3*(i+1)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
list.add(arrayList.subList(0, 3));
list.add(arrayList.subList(3, 6));
list.add(arrayList.subList(6, 9));
ArrayList<Integer> newArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    newArray.addAll(list.get(i));
}
```

You could create a list of lists and loop through that list adding the contents of each sublist to the newArray.

Answer (score 0):

Why not a list of list or array of list:

```
List<List<Integer>> finalList = Arrays.asList(list1, list2, list3);

for (List<Integer> list : finaList) {
    newArray.add(list);
}
```